# Masking email and phone number in Swift 4

Tags: swift

What is the best way to mask / obfuscate email and phone number in Swift 4?

E.g. turning:

- `satheesmk2@gmail.com` into `sa******k2@gmail.com`
- `9876543212` into `98*******2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you could use a function like this. It hides all chars despite the leading and trailing two chars:

```
func hideMidChars(_ value: String) -> String {
   return String(value.enumerated().map { index, char in
      return [0, 1, value.count - 1, value.count - 2].contains(index) ? char : "*"
   })
}
```

Please note there's **currently no special handling** done for very short input strings.

Using this function for the phone number should be trivial; as for the email, if you only want to hide the first part, you could use the following code:

```
let email = "123456@test.com"
let components = email.components(separatedBy: "@")
let result = hideMidChars(components.first!) + "@" + components.last!
```

The `result` constant will be `12**56@test.com`.

This of course assumes that the email is in a valid format, otherwise force unwrapping the first and last array component could crash. However, handling this would be out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can u please explain ( return [0, 1, value.count - 1, value.count - 2].contains(index) ? char : "*" )

Comment: Sorry, I got got to know above line.

Comment: How to implement this in objective C?

Answer (score 9):

```
extension String {

 var maskEmail: String {
        let email = self
        let components = email.components(separatedBy: "@")
        var maskEmail = ""
        if let first = components.first {
            maskEmail = String(first.enumerated().map { index, char in
                return [0, 1, first.count - 1, first.count - 2].contains(index) ? 
char : "*"
            })
        }
        if let last = components.last {
            maskEmail = maskEmail + "@" + last
        }
        return maskEmail
    }


  var maskPhoneNumber: String {
    return String(self.enumerated().map { index, char in
        return [0, 3, self.count - 1, self.count - 2].contains(index) ? 
    char : "*"
    })
     }

}
```